# Primefaces Maven repository not working

Tags: java, primefaces, maven-3

I add repository to my  pom.xml exactly like tihs:

```
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

Then, I start to write:

```
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.prime</groupId>

    </dependency>
```

But in the groupID, only org.primefaces.extensions are available ! Not just org.primefaces. Intellij IDEA shows this.
[image]

When I add this repo to nexus below, it says no repository was found on that URL. I am using latest Maven 3.1.0 downloaded today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The groupID you are using is wrong.

Edit POM file manually and add following.

```
<repository>  
    <id>prime-repo</id>  
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
    <layout>default</layout>  
</repository>  

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>3.5</version>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make my post clear. I ment after typing that part of groupID, IDEA suggests nothing. I know it's incomplete.

Comment: This works in Eclipse. What happens you manually add above and run it. Forget about the IDE .

Comment: This works great, can someone please explain what does this change that makes it actually working ?